# How to add new type to a nested types

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've been trying a lot with this problem without any solution.

The problem: I retrieve a large object from an API. I have to add more properties to this object, everytime I pass this object to a function that adds new properties the type of the object changes because new properties were added.
I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the best way to do this, so let's see:

I have these types declared:

```
export type Match = {
  metadata: Metadata;
  info: Info;
};

export type Info = {
  participants: Participant[];
};

export type Participant = {
  item0: number;
  item1: number;
  item2: number;
  item3: number;
  item4: number;
  item5: number;
  item6: number;
};

export type ItemsAsset = {
    itemAsset0: string;
    itemAsset1: string;
    itemAsset2: string;
    itemAsset3: string;
    itemAsset4: string;
    itemAsset5: string;
    itemAsset6: string;
  };
```

The object I retrieve:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "dataVersion": "1",
        "matchId": "1",
        "participants": [...]
    },
    "info": {
  // more properties
        "participants": [
            {
 // more data
                "item0": 6665,
                "item1": 4637,
                "item2": 3116,
                "item3": 3009,
                "item4": 3024,
                "item5": 3082,
                "item6": 3363,
            }
            // more participants data
        ]
    }
}
```

after passing this object to the first function that add properties:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "dataVersion": "2",
        "matchId": "",
        "participants": [...]
    },
    "info": {
  // more properties
        "participants": [
            {
 // more data
                "item0": 6665,
                "item1": 4637,
                "item2": 3116,
                "item3": 3009,
                "item4": 3024,
                "item5": 3082,
                "item6": 3363,
                "itemAsset0": "http://img/item/6665.png",
                "itemAsset1": "http://img/item/4637.png",
                "itemAsset2": "http://img/item/3116.png",
                "itemAsset3": "http://img/item/3009.png",
                "itemAsset4": "http://img/item/3024.png",
                "itemAsset5": "http://img/item/3082.png",
                "itemAsset6": "http://img/item/3363.png",
            }
            // more participants data
        ]
    }
}
```

"ItemAsset" is the new type that needs to be added to a new type declaration for the new object, if I do:

```
export type MatchWithItemAssetInParticipant = Match & ItemAsset;
```

It doesn't work, and also needs to be inside "Participant" type. If I do:

```
export type MatchWithItemAssetInParticipant = Match & ParticipantItemAsset;

export type ParticipantItemAsset = Participant & {
  itemAsset0: string;
  itemAsset1: string;
  itemAsset2: string;
  itemAsset3: string;
  itemAsset4: string;
  itemAsset5: string;
  itemAsset6: string;
};
```

It doesn't work neither, seems like I can't make changes inside Match type. Hope I was clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: About object you mention to which more properties will be added after being passed to a function, are those properties of the same type? or are they different? can you give us an example of the object?

Comment: I edited the post with object example

Comment: for Participant type, instead of hard coding the types of its properties one by one, you can do: `type Participant = { [key: string]: string | number] } that way it doesn't matter how many new properties the object have, you are telling typescript they will be always of type number or string (which is what I infer from your example), is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. What I want to do is to define a new Type. The same as "Match type" but adding "ItemAsset type" in "Participant type"(you can see the example in post:
`
export type MatchWithItemAssetInParticipant = Match & ParticipantItemAsset;

export type ParticipantItemAsset = Participant & {
  itemAsset0: string;
  itemAsset1: string;
  itemAsset2: string;
  itemAsset3: string;
  itemAsset4: string;
  itemAsset5: string;
  itemAsset6: string;
};
`

This does not work

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE, as described in "[ask] A Good Question".  Right now there are unrelated errors (e.g., `Metadata` is not defined, `ItemAsset` is a typo, etc) and there's no demonstration of the actual problem (you say "this doesn't work" and "that doesn't work either" but that's not a sufficient description for reproducibility).  I engage with a lot of TypeScript questions here, and the ones with a [mre] that people can paste into their IDEs get better and quicker answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `Info` type generic (and subsequently the `Match` type), which allows you to specify the type of `participants`:

```js
export type Info<P = Participant> = {
  participants: P[];
};

export type Match<P = Participant> = {
  metadata: Metadata;
  info: Info<P>;
};
```

Now you can specify the altered participant data:

```js
function loadMatch(): Promise<Match>; // or Promise<Match<Participant>> if you want to write it out
function addParticipantItemAssets(match: Match): Match<Participant & ItemsAsset>
```

When you update the values in your function, typescript will complain, because you will treat Match with regular participants like Match with Participant & ItemAsset at some point.
In that case, use `as` to tell it what kind of object it should think you work with:

```js
function addParticipantItemAssets(match: Match): Match<Participant & ItemsAsset> {
  return match as Match<Participant & ItemsAsset>
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You totally nailed it. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: A generic type is a type variable (i.e. `T` in `type MyArray<T> = T[]`), that refers to a type that will be set when using the type (in contrast to when declaring the type).  It allows you to declare a type as a structure, that works with multiple types (i.e. `Array<number>`, `Array<string>`, `Array<string|number>`, etc), The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) does a better job of explaining it than I can.